# Cross-Platform Mobile Framework Application Starters

Tags: mobile, web, frameworks, cross-platform

I'm currently doing a project on Mobile Web Frameworks, I have gone with Sencha Touch 2.0 and Appcelerator Titanium, since they use quite different approaches. I will be creating the same (or similar) application on both frameworks.

However, as a newbie to these frameworks, I cannot decide what applications to even consider, purely because I do not know how time consuming they will be. I need something that shows a decent amount of framework features, while not requiring a great deal of experience with the frameworks.

So what would be good starter Apps? Any insight or recommendations would be greatly appreciate :) (Sorry if my replies are a little slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Titanium you should definitely check out the sample projects which can be found [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Samples). They are very well documented, you can manipulate the code and you will learn a lot about the framework in very short time. You can also extend the projects quite easily (e.g. include some images, play around with the attributes of objects). However you should do some research before starting an actual project because some native iOs/Android APIs are not/ only partly covered! Especially when it comes to picture manipulation Titanium is not the best choice!.

Comment: Thanks :) didn't realise they had sample projects :D